# The code doesn't work. Could you check the listview builder part specifically in mealdetailscreen class?

Tags: flutter, dart

We have dummy data and a page that will use some information like the title description and image to show the recipe and the image of the meal. The recipe part i couldn't show it doesn't give any error but doesn't work either. Could you hekp me? The code doesn't work. Could you check the listview builder part specifically in mealdetailscreen class?

```
class MealDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Meal meal;

  MealDetailScreen(this.meal);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(meal.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network(
              meal.imageUrl,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 300,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            _buildSectionTitle(context, 'Ingredients'),
            _buildSectionContainer(
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: meal.ingredients.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Card(
                  //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 5,
                      horizontal: 10,
                    ),
                    child: Text(meal.ingredients[index]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _buildSectionTitle(context, 'Steps'),
            _buildSectionContainer(
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: meal.steps.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text('# ${(index + 1)}'),
                      ),
                      title: Text(meal.steps[index]),
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSectionTitle(BuildContext context, String title) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSectionContainer(Widget child) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 200,
      width: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: HOW should anybody check this? Please provide more information.

Comment: Maybe your list of ```ingredients``` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "shrinkWrap" to your ListView.builder.
That's the only problem I see at the moment.

```
_buildSectionContainer(
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true, // <------------------- add shrinkWrap
            itemCount: meal.ingredients.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Card(
              //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              child: Padding(
...
```